# Calculate avg and stddev after filtering out top n values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark DataFrame like

```python
col_a |  col_b |  metric
------------------------
a1    |  b1    |  100
a1    |  b2    |  1
a1    |  b3    |  3
a1    |  b4    |  20
a2    |  b5    |  4
a2    |  b6    |  80
a2    |  b7    |  20
a2    |  b8    |  10
a2    |  b9    |  20
a2    |  b10   |  5
```

Now I want to calculate the average and standard deviation of an aggregation on column `col_a`, after filtering out the top `n` values.

For example, if `n=1` it should calculate the average and standard deviation based on the following filtered table:

```python
col_a |  col_b |  metric
------------------------
a1    |  b2    |  1
a1    |  b3    |  3
a1    |  b4    |  20
a2    |  b5    |  4
a2    |  b7    |  20
a2    |  b8    |  10
a2    |  b9    |  20
a2    |  b10   |  5
```

Which would result in

```python
col_a      | avg   | std
-----------------------------
a1         |  8.0  |  8.5
a2         |  11.8 |  6.9
```

Without this filtering I would run

```python
df.groupby('col_a').agg(f.avg('metric'), f.stddev('metric'))
```

Any idea how I can add a filter like this?

Comment: What would you do in the case of ties. For example, if `n=2` what values should be used for `a2` (since 20 appears twice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an intermediate column to use for filtering. Depending on how you want to handle ties, you can use either [`pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank) or [`pyspark.sql.functions.row_number`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number).

The following example demonstrates the difference:

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

w = Window.partitionBy("col_a").orderBy(f.desc("metric"))
df = df.select(
    "*",
    f.dense_rank().over(w).alias("metric_rank"),
    f.row_number().over(w).alias("metric_row")
)

df.show()
#+-----+-----+------+-----------+----------+
#|col_a|col_b|metric|metric_rank|metric_row|
#+-----+-----+------+-----------+----------+
#|   a2|   b6|    80|          1|         1|
#|   a2|   b7|    20|          2|         2|
#|   a2|   b9|    20|          2|         3|
#|   a2|   b8|    10|          3|         4|
#|   a2|  b10|     5|          4|         5|
#|   a2|   b5|     4|          5|         6|
#|   a1|   b1|   100|          1|         1|
#|   a1|   b4|    20|          2|         2|
#|   a1|   b3|     3|          3|         3|
#|   a1|   b2|     1|          4|         4|
#+-----+-----+------+-----------+----------+
```

Now just filter based on `metric_rank` or `metric_row` and do your aggregation. In your specific example (where `n=1`) there would be no difference:

```python
n = 1
df.where(f.col("metric_rank") > n)\
    .groupby('col_a')\
    .agg(f.avg('metric'), f.stddev_pop('metric'))\
    .show()
#+-----+-----------+------------------+
#|col_a|avg(metric)|stddev_pop(metric)|
#+-----+-----------+------------------+
#|   a2|       11.8| 6.997142273814361|
#|   a1|        8.0| 8.524474568362947|
#+-----+-----------+------------------+
```

(Note: you used [`stddev`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.stddev) which returns the unbiased sample standard deviation, whereas the numbers you showed are actually the population standard deviation, i.e. [`stddev_pop`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.stddev_pop))

However, you can see that if `n=2`, there would be a different result depending on which of the two columns you used for the filter. See how there are two rows with a `metric` of `20` for `a2`. If you want to exclude exactly 2 rows, you should use `metric_row`. If you want to remove all rows where the values are in the top 2, you need to use `metric_rank`.